# Not able to get the index of Form element by loop

Tags: jquery

I am looping through a form elements. again I have a object with id names using the id names i am finding the element. It works But I am not able to get the index of the appropriate element. any one help me?

here is my code :

```
<form>
    <label>UserName <input id="username" type=text /></label>
    <label>Password <input id="password" type=text /></label>
    <label>Email <input id="email" type=text /></label>
    <label>Zipcode <input id="zip" type=text /></label>
    <label>Country <input id="country" type=text /></label>
    <input id="index">
</form>

var obj = ['country', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'zip'];
var elems = $('form').find('input');
var f = $('form');

elems.each(function(i,element){
    console.log($(this).index($(this).parents('form'))); //not working
});

$.each(obj, function(i,label){
    var el = $('#'+label);
    console.log(el.index(el.parents('form'))); //not working - i am looking the answer for this.
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2528/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply use:

```
$(this).parent().index()
```

instead of

```
$(this).index($(this).parents('form'))
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V84Q9/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` and get index as function parameter :

```
elems.each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2528/5/)**